# MP4 H.264 Playback in Chrome -- Audio sounds strange

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video, mp4, video-encoding

When loading this video in Chrome the audio plays super delayed and the video sounds very strange!

http://creative.zebra.com/video/zebra-corporate-video.mp4

Is this an encoding issue?  I am not sure what spec is causing the error and can't find anything on this problem specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys are correct, it was a bug with Chrome.  Fixed in 21.0.1.x.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109978

Answer (score 0):

+1 is a Bug. Report it to http://www.crbug.com. Make sure you keep the original file for reference.

Comment: Do you know of any work around?  Could I change my audio encoding and it would work?  This has been happening for quite some time now and isn't due to a new release.

Comment: I don't know really. What are you coding it with? Are you using ffmpeg's -vcodec libx264? File looks good though (h264/aac) so I don't know. Try swapping the audio layer and see what happens.

Comment: I had someone on my team encode the files for me.  They said they used standard specs, as you already mentioned, so I have no idea.  It plays fine out of Flash which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

does the video play normal in other videoplayers like vlc? actually, this "soundeffect" sounds like your audiofile was f.e. recorded in 96kHz and imported into a 48kHz project without converting to the new sample rate.

EDIT: ...i just downloaded the video and checked it in a normal player, where it looks/sounds good. actually i realized, that your video is played too slow. instead of the 1:10min, it s around double time, so i guess the video tag has some problems with the encoding information in the video...

my guess: HD-videos are recorded in 50fps (frames per second), while NTSC/PAL are recorded in (more or less) 25fps. it's seems like there was something wrong in the encoding, so your video contains a wrong information which makes the video element think, it has some video with 25fps, while the original file has 50fps.